# Split a number in multiples of 60

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula that would split a number in multiples of 60.

Let's say, If the number in 120(A1), answer should be 60(B1) and 60(C1).

If the number is 150(A1), the answer should be 60(B1),60(C1) and 30(D1).

Comment: You may have to consider using a VB script rather than just formulas.

Answer (score 3):

In B1:

```
=IF(A1<60,A1,60)
```

In C2:

```
=IF(OR(B1<60,B1="",SUM($B1:B1)=$A$1),"",MIN(60,$A$1-SUM($B1:B1)))
```

And Drag/Copy over enough columns to cover all potential outcomes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also try this formula in `B1` and copy to `C1:?1` as needed:

```
=IF(COUNT($A1:A1)<=INT($A1/60),60,
IF(COUNT($A1:A1)=1+INT($A1/60),MOD($A1,60),""))
```